# Send two-dimensional array from Nodejs server socket to Ethereum smart contract (Solidity)

Tags: node.js, multidimensional-array, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

Quick question, is there anyone knows how to upload or send a two-dimensional (2D) array from the Nodejs server application to the function declared in the smart contract (Solidity)?

I wish to maintain the index of the 2D array because it will be accessed later for the searching purpose.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a multi-dimensional array in Solidity using multiple `[]` symbols.

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/types.html#arrays

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    function foo(uint256[][] memory _array) external pure returns (uint256[][] memory) {
        return _array;
    }
}
```

Then you can pass the JS multi-dimmensional array using any library for interacting with smart contracts, such as `web3js` ([NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3), [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/)).

```
const array = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
];

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface, address);
contract.methods.foo(array).call().then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I think this is going to work but my program bumps into transaction issue related to the gas and gasPrice, I'll try to open a new question when I'm free, thank you very much for lending your hand!

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I am receiving the error of gasPrice miscalculatian too. Even when i follow the same structure as best as I can. Did you fixed it?

Comment: @Tolstenko gasPrice miscalculation usually points to a general error, such as "something is wrong", and it can be caused by a slight detail different from the working answer. Please ask a separate question with steps to reproduce the issue.